# ROBOTC: Talking to EV3 brain from Android app developed in Xamarin through Bluetooth

Tags: xamarin.android, lego-mindstorms, robotc

This one's a doozy: I'm developing an Android app in Xamarin which will send messages to an EV3 brick running ROBOTC. Anyone think they could help me with this? I understand that NXT bricks can use `sendMessage();` but I'm using an EV3, and can't find a way to use this. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. As for the type of info I wish to send, either strings or, if not, integers will do.

EDIT: Right, I forgot. The app will be for a Kindle Fire, and preferably held in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RobotC does not have Bluetooth support yet (they are [working on it](https://www.facebook.com/groups/legomindstorms/permalink/646052022209694/)). Once they do get it working, you will need the "EV3 Communication Developer Kit" from the [LEGO MINDSTORMS downloads page](http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads). This explains the communication protocol. In particular, look for the "mailbox" instructions. This is how messages are passed back and forth between applications.

Comment: Got it. In that case, I will await their support, and, meanwhile, work on the app for the Kindle. Thanks for the help!